# An error occurred while starting the kernel

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, spyder

I keep seeing this message.

```
An error ocurred while starting the kernel
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Excel\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
"__main__", mod_spec)
File "C:\Users\Excel\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "C:\Users\Excel\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder_kernels\console\__main__.py", line 11, in 
start.main()
File "C:\Users\Excel\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder_kernels\console\start.py", line 279, in main
import_spydercustomize()
File "C:\Users\Excel\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder_kernels\console\start.py", line 39, in import_spydercustomize
import spydercustomize
File "C:\Users\Excel\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 5, in 
from utilities import visualize_classifier
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utilities'
```

I tried the following . . .

Try typing these 3 lines from the anaconda command prompt:

```
conda create -n spyder python=3.7 spyder
activate spyder
spyder
```

Also . . .

```
pip install --upgrade spyder
```

Unfortunately, nothing has worked thus far.  Is there some kind of master reset to force this to startup correctly?  Thanks a lot.

Comment: Looks like an old version because the current `spyder-kernels` doesn't have that import statement. I checked the anaconda repository and it looks like there are [3 repos](https://anaconda.org/search?q=spyder+kernels) with this package one is version 0.3.0, the other is 1.2.0, and the last is 1.0.1. I'm going to guess and say its trying to install the earliest one. Try uninstalling spyder and spyder-kernels and run this `conda install spyder-kernels` to reinstall.

Comment: Yeap, yeap, that worked.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: No problem, happy to help. I'll post this as an answer below if you don't mind.

Answer (score 1):

Try uninstalling `spyder` and `spyder-kernels` and run this to reinstall.

```
conda install spyder-kernels
```